# Observable collection not firing setter or updating C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not entirely sure why this is not updating. So in my application you can modify the users name on the right side using the textbox. The changes reflect in real time on the left. When you click the 'Add New License' button it creates a new license and adds it to the selected customer. However the listview column 'Lincenes' doesn't appear to update in order to reflect the number of licenses the customer has. As a test i placed a print statement in my Obs collection here

```
        private ObservableCollection<License> licenses;
        public ObservableCollection<License> Licenses
        {
            get { return licenses ?? (licenses = new ObservableCollection<License>()); }
            set
            {
                Console.Write("Modified");
                Set(ref licenses, value);
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LicensesCount));
            }
        }
```

However I've noticed it never gets printed for some reason. I'm rather stumped on what to do or change. Below are the main bits of my Code. Both the customer and License class objects are of base class INotify...

[image]
[image]

**Customer.cs and License.cs classes**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using WpfApplication1.Helper;

namespace WpfApplication1.Model
{
    public class Customer : NotifyBase
    {
        private string firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set { Set(ref firstName, value); }
        }

        public string LicensesCount
        {
            get { return this.Licenses.Count.ToString(); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<License> licenses;
        public ObservableCollection<License> Licenses
        {
            get { return licenses ?? (licenses = new ObservableCollection<License>()); }
            set
            {
                Console.Write("Modified");
                Set(ref licenses, value);
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LicensesCount));
            }
        }

        public Customer(string firstname, string lastname, string email, string company)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstname;
        }

        // Commands
        private ICommand addNewLicense_Command;
        public ICommand AddNewLicense_Command
        {
            get { return addNewLicense_Command ?? (addNewLicense_Command = new RelayCommand<Customer>(n =>{ AddNewLicense_Execute(n); }));}
        }

        public void AddNewLicense_Execute(Customer customer)
        {
            Licenses.Add(new License("Paint"));
        }
    }


    public class License : NotifyBase
    {
        private string product;
        public string Product
        {
            get { return product; }
            set { Set(ref product, value); }
        }

        public License(string product)
        {
            this.Product = product;
        }

    }

}
```

**NotifyBase.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace WpfApplication1.Helper
{
    public abstract class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the solution: [Solution Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukes8d9f3mghz7f/ObsUpdate.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are updating `LicensesCount` when you set new `ObservableCollection` to `Licenses` property. When new `License` object is added `Licenses` property isn't changing. To update `LicensesCount` properly you should listen to `CollectionChanged` event of your `licenses` observable collection.

It should look simillar to this:

```
private ObservableCollection<License> licenses;
public ObservableCollection<License> Licenses
{
    get { return licenses ?? (licenses = CreateLicensesCollection()); }
    set
    {
        Console.Write("Modified");
        Set(ref licenses, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LicensesCount));
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<License> CreateLicensesCollection()
{
    var collection = new ObservableCollection<License>();
    collection.CollectionChanged += (s, a) => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LicensesCount));
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: i see, that clears things up. thank you for helping out. 
Is there a way i could add this to an ObservableObjectEx class? so it applies to any class that is of Observable object. it seems safer to do that.

Comment: understandable. thank you for your help though! you got the answer correct

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you directly bind to `Count` property of ObservableCollection? Change the binding source in xaml from `LicensesCount` to `Licenses.Count`. Since the ObservableCollection has built-in functionality of INotifyPropertyChanged, no additional coding is required.

Comment: Saved my day. I was working on XAML converter in Xamarin Forms (currently known as MAUI). I wanted to bind a value and check if the `ObservableCollection<T>` is empty. Hence. Now I pass `{Binding MyCollection.Count, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToBooleanConverter}}` from XAML. Thanks.